# CakePHP error query with integer

Tags: php, postgresql, cakephp, authentication

I state that I am new to CakePHP, I moved a site made with CakePHP on a new server, using Postgres as a database (version 8.4 on the old server, the new server 9.4), my problem is that the new server can not logging in with the plugin Auth.

This is my code, but I can not understand why:

```
if(isset($this->data) && !isset($this->data['User']['username_owner']) 
&& isset($this->data['User']['guest_access_key'])) {

    $dbuser = $this->User->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'User.guest_access_key' => $this->data['User']['guest_access_key'],
            'User.valid_to >=' => date("d-m-Y"),
            'User.active'=> 1,
            'User.list_type_id' => 1
         )
    )); //ecc..
```

If I go to debug, I find that in this query changes me the last state

```
'User.list_type_id'=>1
```

the query is shown thus:

```
User.list_type_id = '\x31'
```

why?

Comment: I improved your post formatting and I found `'User.list_type_id' = >1`. Do you have same at your code? (should be `'User.list_type_id' =>1`)

Comment: No, my code is as follows: 'User.list_type_id'=>1